# Gridview + Scrollview - Need help/suggestions

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I´ve got some problems with the current design of my app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AxBK.png
Nothing special, imageview in the top left corner, 2 tables and a gridview (with custom layout, 1 imageview, 2 textviews) on the bottom.

This is working without any problems on big screens/tablets but on small(er) screens (phones), where I have to use a scrollview, I get some problems with that gridview.

After looking around for some time I came to the conclusion that you shouldn´t use a gridview in a scrollview...

I really wanted to use a gridview because it manages the available space itself without creating different layouts for each screensize.

So, what else could/should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Delete the `ScrollView`.

Step #2: If the "imageview in the top left corner, 2 tables" means that "on small(er) screens (phones)" the `GridView` is unusable, either reduce the size of the "imageview in the top left corner, 2 tables" or come up with another navigation pattern (e.g., "imageview in the top left corner, 2 tables" on one tab, `GridView` on another tab).